# Phonegap db encryption: where should I store the password?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, encryption

I'm building an app on Phonegap (iOS and Android). Users sign up and then they can write private notes.
When they launch the app, they have to sign in on the remote server, there's the sync between remote and local (encrypted with user's password) db and then they can view their notes from local db.
The problem is: I want to ask them for the password only once, not every note they want to read.

Is there a way to safely share db's password between webviews, so that I can initialize on every page the encrypted websql db?
Alternatively, is there a way to initialize only once the encrypted db and to access it from different webviews?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Would you mind clarifying some things for me?  For example, why are you encrypting the local stores?  No one will have access to them except your app.  Also, how are you dealing with authentication?  OAuth?

Comment: @GrantAmos-Enragedmrt i don't think it's a good idea to store sensitive data in a cleartext websql db, so I wanted to use user's pass as local db pass, but in this way I have to keep it in memory. 

I'm dealing with authentication exactly as I do in browser experience: I send with POST under SSL the credentials to the server.

Comment: Well, it's bad on a PC to store it in plain-text, but on device it shouldn't matter.  The device's phonegap instance is stored in a WebView with it's own private cache.  So long as the application itself is secure, the phonegap portion will be as well.  The insecure parts are storing things in javascript/html as plain-text, since these files can be read from your APK.

Comment: @GrantAmos-Enragedmrt wouldn't it be possible to get the webview private cache in a rooted device?

Comment: @momo Yes, that's correct.  In a rooted device nothing is hidden from the user (they are root).  That said, I don't think it matters.  If a user wants to access their own private data, that's ok.  The key is securing the data from other applications or users and unless you gives those apps root access, that security should hold.  (This is my basic understanding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer. But if it helps someone.

If it's really necessary then an encryption decryption can be performed inside the app. Before saving the password in database like websql you can perform an encryption with your **custom** way and decrypt password with js after retrieval. This way your password is safe in database. Though as grant mentioned, there is no need for it in mobile device.